# Bing geocoding web service bad results

Tags: geocoding, bing-maps

I'm trying to use the Bing Geocoding web service in order to convert adresses to Location in order to add on the Bing WPF Control in my WinForm Application.

My problem is that somes adresses are correctly found by geocoding and some other adresses no !

If i search this adress directly on tha bing maps website it's found.

**Here is my sample :**

```
public static GeocodeResponse GetGeocodeResponse(string appId, string address)
    {
        GeocodeRequest geocodeRequest = new GeocodeRequest
        {
            Credentials = new Credentials {ApplicationId = appId},
            Query = address
        };
        ConfidenceFilter[] filters = new ConfidenceFilter[1];
        filters[0] = new ConfidenceFilter { MinimumConfidence = Confidence.High };
        GeocodeOptions geocodeOptions = new GeocodeOptions { Filters = filters };
        geocodeRequest.Options = geocodeOptions;

        GeocodeServiceClient geocodeServiceClient = new GeocodeServiceClient("BasicHttpBinding_IGeocodeService");
        return geocodeServiceClient.Geocode(geocodeRequest);
    }
```

Anyone have same tips in order to solve this ?

Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

There are several possible things that can be causing this. The first is that you are using a basic or trial account and your requests are being rate limited. This occurs when the servers are under a lot of load or when you make a lot of requests at a frequency that would exceed the free terms of use. This is done to ensure that Enterprise accounts are not affected by the usage of basic or trial users. When rate limiting occurs a flag is added to the header of the response to indicate this:

You are using the old legacy Bing Maps SOAP service which has not been updated in over 4 years. It is generally not recommended to do any new development against those services as they are much slower, have less features and generally return less accurate results than the Bing Maps REST services. I would recommend moving over to the Bing Maps REST services. You can find documentation on how to use them in .NET here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701713.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj819168.aspx

Also, take a look at this blog post:
http://rbrundritt.wordpress.com/2013/02/14/bing-maps-rest-service-tips-amp-tricks-2/

I also cover how to use the REST services in depth in my free eBook in Chapter 5:
http://rbrundritt.wordpress.com/my-book/